# Drag and Drop: Create columns dynamically when the element is dropped

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I'm using react-beautiful-dnd to copy and element drop into a columns previously created.

But I wonder if there is any possibility when I'm dragging an element and I drop it, it creates me the column dynamically to drop it ? could I make it ?

if react-beautiful-dnd doesn't work, what other plugin of React could do it ?

any suggestion..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am curious about the same thing, but I suspect that it is **not** possible.

The approach I can think of is to make the parent of your droppable columns also a `Droppable` itself. Then `onDragEnd` you could determine where to insert a new column, automatically adding the `Draggable`.

While the documentation has a page for [Changes while dragging](https://github.com/atlassian/react-beautiful-dnd/blob/master/docs/guides/changes-while-dragging.md), it includes these rules (and others) that make me think this approach will not work:

- You can only add or remove `Draggables` that are of the same type as the dragging item.
- You cannot add or remove a `<Droppable />` during a drag.

Also note the warning (currently, at the top of the page) that changes while dragging are currently only supported in version **`11.x`**

Answer (score 0):

Yup, so first control your columns with some state variable say `this.state.columns`

Then, add an event listener, probably `onDragEnd()`. In the event handler, update your `columns` state so that the update occurs as you want

Comment: ok good option but that I need is when I'm dragging in a spot where there is not a columns to drop it, it allows me a columns dynamically to drop the element that I'm dragging in that moment. For Example: I have 2 columns of elements but I drag a new element and I want tot drop it in de middle of the 2 columns. I would need to create dynamically a new columns in the middle of 2 columns already created, also at the same time drop the element in that column that I created dynamically.

Comment: Add the empty columns anyway? Style them different? Maybe a + symbol when empty?